# How do I calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^\frac{1}{n} (n+1)^\frac{1}{n+1} ...... (2n)^\frac{1}{2n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How do I calculate the limit of the following sequence?
 $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}} (n+1)^\frac{1}{n+1} ...... (2n)^\frac{1}{2n}$$

Comment: I'm not sure if it'd work but try taking its logarithm and calculating the infinite sum?

Comment: @grdgfgr There is no infinite sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each factor $(n + k)^{1 \over n + k}$ is at least $n^{1 \over 2n}$ since $n + k \geq n$ and ${1 \over n + k} \geq {1 \over 2n}$. More rigorously you might write
$$(n + k)^{1 \over n + k} \geq n^{1 \over n + k} \geq n^{1 \over 2n}$$

So the product of all $n + 1$ factors is at least $(n^{1 \over 2n})^{n+1} > (n^{1 \over 2n})^n = n^{ 1 \over 2}$. This goes to infinity as $n$ goes to infinity, and therefore your product does too.

Comment: Not that it changes anything substantial, but there are $n+1$ factors. Good low-tech solution.

Comment: Good. Thank you very much; I didn't think of this comparison.

Answer (score 7):

The logarithm of the limiting quantity is:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{n+k}\ln(n+k)$ $= \displaystyle\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+\tfrac{k}{n}}\left(\ln n + \ln\left(1+\tfrac{k}{n}\right)\right) $ $= \displaystyle\dfrac{\ln n}{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{1+\tfrac{k}{n}} + \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\dfrac{\ln\left(1+\tfrac{k}{n}\right)}{1+\tfrac{k}{n}}$

The second term is a Riemann sum for $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx$.

The first term is $\ln n$ multiplied by a Riemann sum for $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{1+x}\,dx$.

That should be enough to tell you what the limit is.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this is not the kind of solution I'm looking for.

Comment: If you are looking for a specific type of solution, don't make people who are trying to help you *waste their time* and only tell them afterwards. Put the rules in the question, not after people have done the work. @user62029

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for?

Comment: Nice solution by JimmyK4542.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm not looking for a specific type of solution, but only for a simpler one, since this one (which is otherwise fine) is overly complicated with respect to the course I'm following.

Comment: You most certainly *are* looking  for a specific kind of solution, because you've said as much. @user62029

Answer (score 3):

First, show that:

$$m^{1/m}=e^{\log(m)/m}\geq 1+\frac{\log m}{m}$$

So:

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{m=n}^{2n} m^{1/m}&\geq \prod_{m=n}^{2n}\left(1+\frac{\log m}{m}\right)\\
&\geq 1+\sum_{m=n}^{2n}\frac{\log m}{m}\\
&\geq 1+\int_n^{2n}\frac{\log x}{x}dx\\
&=1+\frac12\left(\log^2(2n)-\log^2(n)\right)\\
&=1+\frac{1}{2}\left(\log(2n)-\log(n)\right)\left(\log(2n)+\log(n)\right)\\
&=1+\frac{1}{2}\log(2)\left(2\log(n)+\log(2)\right)
\end{align}$$

So, the sequence converges to $+\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Easier way:

First, take the logarithm:

$$\frac{\ln(n)}{n} + \frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} + \cdots + \frac{\ln(2n)}{2n}$$

Notice that $f(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ is a decreasing function after $x = e$ (i.e, it is eventually decreasing). Thus, for sufficiently large $n$:

$$\frac{\ln(n)}{n} + \frac{\ln(n+1)}{n+1} + \cdots + \frac{\ln(2n)}{2n} > \frac{\ln(2n)}{2n} + \frac{\ln(2n)}{2n} + \cdots + \frac{\ln(2n)}{2n} = (n+1) \cdot \frac{\ln(2n)}{2n}$$

(Replacing each term with $\frac{\ln(2n)}{2n}$ is valid because this is the smallest term in the series, because $f(x)$ is decreasing.)

The limit of $(n+1) \cdot \frac{\ln(2n)}{2n}$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$ is infinity.

Since the logarithm of your original product is infinite, your original product is infinite.